# Store information from a File in a Class object (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to read in an input file into a Class object using C++.

Here the class object
I was trying to just read the file input into an array but i had problems reading in the lines after the "Polygon" keyword.

```
 class Polygon{
   public:
  int object_number;
  float point_count;
  float Px[SIZE][SIZE];
  float Py[SIZE][SIZE];
  float Pz[SIZE][SIZE];
  float Nx[SIZE], Ny[SIZE], Nz[SIZE];  


};
```

I want to be able to store all the information after the Polygon keyword until the next Polygon keyword.

So, for the first Polygon in the File.

```
  object_number = 0; 
    point_count = 4;
    Px[0][0] = 100; 
Py[0][0]= 100; 
Pz[0][0] = 200; 
Nx[0][0] = 0.398925;
 Ny[0][0] =0.598388;
 Nz[0][0] = -0.453324;
```

And so forth until it reaches the next "Poylgon" keyword in the file. I'm going to use the information to perform some phong shading calculations

The File contains.

```
Polygon 0 4
100 100 200 0.398925 0.598388 -0.453324
125 100 178 0.352837 0.646868 -0.490051
125 125 145 0.396981 0.595472 -0.551363
100 125 167 0.448836 0.550844 -0.510041
Polygon 1 4
100 125 167 0.448836 0.550844 -0.510041
125 125 145 0.396981 0.595472 -0.551363
125 150 118 0.447405 0.521972 -0.621396
100 150 140 0.505846 0.482853 -0.574825
Polygon 0 4
100 150 140 0.505846 0.482853 -0.574825
125 150 118 0.447405 0.521972 -0.621396
125 175 97 0.501037 0.417531 -0.695885
100 175 119 0.566484 0.386239 -0.643732
Polygon 1 4
100 175 119 0.566484 0.386239 -0.643732
125 175 97 0.501037 0.417531 -0.695885
125 200 82 0.501037 0.417531 -0.695885
100 200 104 0.566484 0.386239 -0.643732


 .......
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicates of [c++ read file struct](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+structure&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a fairly specific reason to do otherwise (such as needing to pass all the points to the GPU as a single block of memory), it's probably going to be a lot easier to break this up into more manageable pieces.

```
class point { 
    float px, py, pz, nx, ny, nz;
    // not sure about their order in the file, so you may need to fix this:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, point &p) { 
       return is >> p.nx >> p.ny >> p.nz >> p.px >> p.py >> p.pz;
    }
};

class polygon { 
    int object_number;
    std::vector<point> points;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, polygon &p) { 
        int point_count;
        std::string check;
        is >> check;
        if (check != "polygon") {
           is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
           return is;
        }
        is >> p.object_number >> point_count;
        for (int i=0; i<p.object_number; i++) {
            point p2;
            is >> p2;
            p.points.push_back(p2);
        }
        return is;
    }
};
```

From there, we can read an entire file full of polygons fairly easily:

```
std::ifstream in("mypolygons.txt");

std::vector<polygon> polygons { std::istream_iterator<polygon>(in),
                                std::istream_iterator<polygon>() };
```